# Is it possible to find out what people from specific state searched for in my website through Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I know that by going to **Audience>Geo>Location** I can see which state uses my website the most

Is there a way to tell what search term/keywords the people in those state uses the most when they visit my website?

When I put in "keyword" and "search query" as secondary dimension in analytics, the result is (not set) or (not provided).

Is it something with my settings or is it google not letting us view user search by state?

Is there another analytics tool that would give me that info?

Answer (score 1):

Back in 2010,  Google announced that it would no longer provide the keyword data as a result personalising our search experiences based on our behaviour, and this change has been implemented in the interest of protecting the privacy of the searcher.

I believe Google did it also to push on Google Ads, in that case it is possible to know the keywords entered by users who click on the ads link.

Comment: thank you for the reply. yeah i know how to find the keywords used when they clicked my ads but i believed thats just mixed of all users yeah? no way to segregate them